# Parse JSON with PHP and output to CSV

Tags: php, json

I'm wondering how I can use PHP to parse the JSON below and output the parsed values into CSV format.

```
{
 "test":{"12345":"98765","56789":"54321"},
 "control":{"99999":"98765","88888":"98765"}
}
```

I would like to extract just the keys from the `test` array (i.e. `12345`, `56789`) and have them returned in CSV format. Is that possible to do using json_decode?

Please feel free to ask any questions if you need more information

Comment: all the values on one row or for each value one row? and do you want to output as web-page or locally to a file?

Comment: each value one row, please

Comment: What's CSV about one value/line though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
fputcsv(fopen('file', 'w'), array_keys($json['test']));
```

Comment: crap.. didnt see the true.. sorry buddy.. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = '{
 "test":{"12345":"98765","56789":"54321"},
 "control":{"99999":"98765","88888":"98765"}
}';


$json = json_decode($s, true);
echo implode("\n", array_keys($json['test']));
```

Would that do?

Comment: This worked, but did not output to a CSV file. Thanks though!

Comment: @585connor writing to a file is something you probably should read up on then. :) See http://se1.php.net/file_put_contents